# On click how to only show collection entries with task: 'Test'?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

The code below only loads data where task has the entry ‘Test’.

```
Meteor.publish 'activities', ->
  Activities.find(task: 'Test')
```

How can I achieve the same when a button is clicked when the code is:

```
Meteor.publish 'activities', ->
  Activities.find()
```

Here’s my code so far:

Client:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click .ButtonDemo': function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Successful click");
    activities: Activities.find({task: 'Test'}).fetch()
  }
});
```

Router:

```
@route "dashboard",
path: "/dashboard"
waitOn: ->
  [
    subs.subscribe 'activities'
  ]
data: ->
  activities: Activities.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the (core) [reactive-var package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) to your project: `meteor add reactive-var`.

Then:

On the server, change your publication to take an argument:

```js
Meteor.publish('activities', (filter = {}) => { return Activities.find(filter); });
```

On the client, declare the reactive variable:

```
const filter = new ReactiveVar({})
```

Change your subscription to take that variable as argument:

```
Meteor.subscribe('activities', filter);
```

and set that variable on click:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click .ButtonDemo': () => {
    console.log("Successful click");
    filter.set({task: 'Test'});
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried the above, whilst replacing activities for posts in a new Meteor project. It's not working for me though I'm sure this is due to my placing the code inside dashboard.js, I'm post this outside the comment due to character limits. I've added reactive-var to be clear and I'm using Meteor 1.7 if that makes any difference to this.

Comment: client / views / dashboard / dashboard.html:

Comment: <template name="dashboard">
<form>
<button class="ButtonDemo">Click</button>
</form>
{{> posts}}
</template>

Comment: client / views / dashboard / dashboard.js:

Comment: const filter = new ReactiveVar({})
 Meteor.subscribe('posts', filter);
 Template.dashboard.events({
   'click .ButtonDemo': () => {
     console.log("Successful click");
     filter.set({title: 'Test'});
     return false;
   }
 });

Comment: server / publish / collections.js:

Comment: Meteor.publish('posts', (filter = {}) => { return Posts.find(filter); });

Comment: lib/router/main.js:

Comment: Router.map(function() {
  this.route("home", {
    path: "/",
    layoutTemplate: "homeLayout"
  });
  return this.route("dashboard", {
    path: "/dashboard",
    waitOn: function() {
      return [subs.subscribe('posts')];
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        posts: Posts.find({}, {
          sort: {
            createdAt: -1
          }
        }).fetch()
      };
    }
  });
});

Comment: You need to remove `waitOn: function() { return [subs.subscribe('posts')]; }` -- it will subscribe to the full collection, overriding your partial subscription.